# Reset primary key for all rows of mysql table starting at specific value

Tags: mysql

Hello is there a mysql command to loop through all rows of a table and reset the primary key starting at specific value, e.g. from 5000 upwards?
I do NOT simply want to reset the primary key for the next input but update all existing rows.

This is not what I need:

```
ALTER TABLE t1 AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a variable and update it after setting the value in each row. (e.g: assuming your column name is `id`):

```
SET @startVal=5000 - 1; # we will increment startVal in every loop so we subtract 1 to begin with
UPDATE t1 SET id=(@startVal:=@startVal+1);
```